# Cyclic hierarchy in inheritance

Tags: java, compiler-construction, programming-languages

I am currently writing a compiler for java. The JLS says "The class hierarchy must be acyclic." but what about the case where:

```
            B extends A
            C extends A

            D extends B
            D extends C
```

This is an acyclic graph but invalid how can i detect this case? I am currently using a BFS and whenever i see a back-edge i know there is a cycle but the BFS algorithm doesn't detect the case mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`D` inherits from more than one class and multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. This is how you detect it.

Comment: So a class deceleration of the form : Class A extends B,C is invalid correct ?

Answer (score 0):

If your tree represents the class inheritance hierarchy, just add a check for ensuring that class X doesn't already `extend` some other class, before inserting a new `X extends` relation into the tree.